# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have concern of seeing this error. Does it matter or good practice to ignore this error. I have 2 different pages. One page have extra coloumn and i am calling this javascript fucntion on master page so that script can be used on all the pages. 
divValue[3].innerHTML is the extra coloumn. so this gives an error when it dont find the divvalue[3] index in one of the page. So how can i handle this.

below is my code

```
 dateValue = tableRow[t].getElementsByTagName('nobr'); 
            console.log(dateValue);
            divValue = tableRow[t].getElementsByTagName('div'); // look for <div> tag inside the <tr> tag and store the child element value of td tag.

            startDate = dateValue [0].innerHTML; // store the start date. 
            console.log(startDate);
            endDate = dateValue [1].innerHTML;// store the end date.
            console.log(endDate); 
            divValue[1].innerHTML = calculation(startDate,endDate);  // manipulate the calculated value with the original value.
            console.log(divValue);

            divValue[3].innerHTML = activeDays(startDate,endDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple truthy/falsy condition should work.  This will prevent it from trying to find the innerHTML of something that doesn't exist.

```
if (divValue[3])
   divValue[3].innerHTML = activeDays(startDate,endDate);
```

Comment: Thanks @Seano666 I tried if condition using the length of the divValue. But it was not woking. But your answer helped me.